# Computing leading and trailing sets for context-free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I am seeking for a detailed algorithm describing how to generate leading and trailing sets for non-terminal symbols in context-free grammars.

I've found something like this:
https://pl.scribd.com/doc/51358638/16/Operator-Precedence-Relations 
but I'm unsure about how it works. (See page 20)

Assume, that we have productions:

> A -> YaZ | B
>
> B -> b

then, it is said, that Leading(A) = {a}, Leading(A) = Leading(B) and Leading(B)={b}.
And I have my doubts about this:

1. Does it mean, that Leading(A) = {a, b} ? - I assume that in every step we do not replace the set already generated because of '=', but make sum of two sets.
2. Does it mean, that Leading(B) is {b} or {a, b}? - Does the third rule mean, that we add Leading(B) to Leading(A) or that Leading(A) and Leading(B) are equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Leading` and `Trailing` are functions specific to generating an operator-precedence parser, which is only applicable if you have an operator precedence grammar. An operator precedence grammar is a special case of an operator grammar, and an operator grammar has the important property that *no production has two consecutive non-terminals*.

(An operator precedence grammar is, loosely speaking, an operator grammar which can be parsed with an operator precedence parser :-). But that's not important for now.)

Given an operator grammar, the function `Leading` (resp. `Trailing`) of a non-terminal produces the set of terminals which could be (recursively) the first (resp. last) terminal in some sentential form derived from that non-terminal.

Another possibly more intuitive definition is that a terminal is in the Leading set for a non-terminal if the terminal is "visible" from the beginning of a production. Non-terminals are "transparent", so a terminal could be visible either by looking through a leading non-terminal or by looking into a visible non-terminal.

For example, a standard expression grammar (which is an operator grammar; no production has two consecutive non-terminals):

```
expr   -> factor '*' expr
expr   -> factor
factor -> term '+' factor
factor -> term
term   -> ID
term   -> '(' expr ')'
```

From `term`, `ID` and `(` are visible from the beginning, and `ID` and `)` are visible from the end. `expr` is not visible from either side, because it is hidden by terminals, so we don't need to consider it.

From `factor`, `+` is visible from both ends, and `factor` also inherits the Leading and Trailing sets of `term` because `term` is visible from both ends. (`factor` is also visible from the end in itself, but that cannot add anything new to the Trailing set.)

Finally, from `expr`, `*` is visible from both ends, and `expr` inherits from `factor`.

So we end up with:

```
Non-terminal            Leading             Trailing
expr                    *, +, ID, (         *, +, ID, )
factor                  +, ID, (            +, ID, )
term                    ID, (               ID, )
```

From that, we're going to construct precedence relations. Basically, if you find

```
nonterminal TERMINAL
```

in any production, then you add the precedence relations `TRAIL ⋗ TERMINAL` for every `TRAIL` in `Trailing(nonterminal)`. Similarly, every occurrence of

```
TERMINAL nonterminal
```

generates the relationships `TERMINAL ⋖ LEAD` for every `LEAD` in `Leading(nonterminal)`. And finally, if you find

```
TERMINAL1 TERMINAL2
```

or

```
TERMINAL1 nonterminal TERMINAL2
```

then you generate the relationship `TERMINAL1 ·=· TERMINAL2`.

Once you've generated all the precedence relationships, you look at every pair of terminals `T, U`. If at most one precedence relation holds -- that is, `T ⋖ U, T ⋗ U, T ·=· U` or there is no relationship from `T` to `U` -- then you have an operator precedence grammar. (There is no connection between `T, U` and `U, T`. Precedence relationships are not antisymmetric and it is unfortunate that they are traditionally spelled with symbols that look like numeric comparison.)

Answer (score 2):

Leading(A) = { a,b }  since:

1. A -> YaZ and 'a' is the first terminal;
2. A -> B and B -> b, so:
   i) b in Leading(B) (b is an element of set Leading(B)), and
   ii) Leading(B) belongs to Leading(A) (Leading(B) is a subset of Leading(A)).

That is, A =>* YaZ and A =>* b, so { a,b } = Leading(A).