# Leading and Trailing in Ambiguous Operator Precedence grammar parsing

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ambiguous

[Click for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFOdy.png) Consider the grammar E-> E+E | E*E | id.
When you try to solve this ambiguous grammar with the help of leading and trailing, it gives errors and becomes inconsistent. How are we supposed to solve ambiguous operator precedence grammars?

Comment: Leading and trailing what? And what do you mean by "operator precedence grammar"? (I know what it means. I want you to tell me what you mean by the term, because as far as I am concerned an ambiguous grammar cannot be a precedence grammar -- the ambiguity will make it impossible to compute the precedence relation.)

Comment: check this answer which tells about Leading and trailing sets in operator precedence grammar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397767/computing-leading-and-trailing-sets-for-context-free-grammar

Comment: Yes, I wrote that answer. Your grammar is not an operator precedence grammar, so you will not be able to compute consistent precedence relations. In order to make the grammar into an operator precedence grammar, you will need to rewrite it so that it is unambiguous.

Comment: Oh, okay! I get it now. Thank you!!